# Is there a known algorithm to get the relative locations of n unknown points, based on known distances between them?

Tags: math, triangulation

I have a set of 10 points in 3D space. 
the only information that I have is the distance from every point to every other point.

I can arbitrarily set one point as (0,0,0), and another as my X axis (distance,0,0).

Now, it seems that I should be able to use these two known points to locate all the other points in 3D space (relative to the first two).

Do I have enough information to do this?
Is there an existing algorithm that I should be looking at?

Comment: I do not have much time to explain as a complete answer, but take a look at [Multilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_range_multilateration) for methods of finding points and [Distance Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry) (Look at the section "Embedding") for how to ensure that a unique solution exists (if it exists at all) giving your data.

Comment: to find the points (from 3 known ones) simply compute intersection of 3 spheres and chose point satisffying distance condition to known points. The first few points might have more than one possibilities so chose one...

Answer (score 0):

For the first three points, I can:

```
//store first one as zero point

        if (pos.id == 0)
        {
            pos.position = Eigen::Vector3d(0, 0, 0);    
        }

        //store second as X axis
        if (pos.id == 1)
        {
            pos.position = Eigen::Vector3d(<Distance from 1 to 2>, 0, 0);
        }

        //triangulate third from distances
        if (pos.id == 2)
        { 
            double c =  //distance from 3 to 1
            double b =  //distance from 3 to 2
            double a =  //distance from 1 to 2

            pos.position.x() = (c*c - b * b + a * a) / (2 * a);
            pos.position.y() = std::sqrt(c*c - pos.position.x()*pos.position.x());



        }
```

code for the third point from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543961/determine-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-known)

Now i can run multilateration for the following points, as suggested in a comment, using the three known points.